# Custom attribute address in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, attributes

We're experiencing the same problem, even in Magento 2.2.7 version.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619136/magento2-save-new-address-attribute-in-checkout

Newly added custom attributes are present on first "Shipping" step but when on "Review & Payments" step these fields are no longer present, hence not sent to form.
Or in our case, an error apper since they are required and values are not set.

Did someone find how to solve it?

In my case:

```
    $attributesInfo = [
        'gsp_address_type'  => [
            'label' => __('Address Type'),
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => 'Mod\Module\Model\Data\AddressType',
            'position' => 1,
            'visible' => 1,
            'required' => 1,
        ],
    ];

    foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
    }

    foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode);
        $attribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
        );
        $attribute->save();
    }
```

[image]
[image]